# Echoing the sum of a table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, sum

I have 2 columns in a table called Points. The 2 columns are UserPoints and UserID.

I want to be able to echo the total amount of points a user has.

I've got something like this but I dont think its right.

```
$getTotalPoints = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(UserPoints) FROM `Points` WHERE `UserID` = '1'") or die(mysql_error()); 
$totalPoints = mysql_fetch_array($getTotalPoints);
```

When i echo the above statement by echoing "$totalPoints" i get "Array".

Anyone know the correct query to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting `Array` because that's what's stored in `$totalPoints`. Look closely at your code and you'll see you used the `mysql_fetch_array()` function, which retrieves a row of results from the results set as an array. If you do `var_dump()` on `$totalPoints` you'll see the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12345
    [SUM(UserPoints)] => 12345
)
```

The sum you're looking for is at index 0 or the column name, in this case `SUM(UserPoints)`, so you can output it using `echo $totalPoints[0]` or `echo $totalPoints['SUM(UserPoints)']`.

Alternatively, you could use the `mysql_result()` function. I think this is more in-line with the behavior you were expecting.  It fetches a single value from the row from the result set. So, instead of `mysql_fetch_array()` you'd wrote:

```
$totalPoints = mysql_result($result, 0);
```

For more information on `mysql_result()`, check out the [PHP documentation for it](http://php.net/mysql_result).

As an aside, I would recommend not using mysql_* functions if you have the option. A newer interface like PDO, or at least mysqli, would be better. This will depend on your project of course... if you're working with a large legacy code base it may be difficult to change. But if you're starting out now, I think you'd benefit from the newer libraries. You can see my opinion and some guidance on transitioning extensions in this [article I wrote](http://phpmaster.com/migrate-from-the-mysql-extension-to-pdo/).

Hope this helped... and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

mysql_fetch_array fetches a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both. by default it creates both. all that you need is to `echo $totalPoints[0];`

or, if you rewrite you request as

```
$getTotalPoints = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(UserPoints) total FROM `Points` 
        WHERE `UserID` = '1'") or die(mysql_error()); 
$totalPoints = mysql_fetch_array($getTotalPoints);
echo $totalPoints['total'];
```

Answer (score 1):

mysql_fetch_array returns an array. Therefore you need to treat `$totalpoints` as an array.

try adding this line to the end of your snippet:

`echo $totalPoints[0];`

There are several ways to retrieve data with the mysql functions I suggest reading about them in the php manual.

Here is [mysql_fetch_array](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Answer (score 1):

The resultset row is an array with as many elements as you got in the SELECT.
In you case you only got 1 element (the sum).
So you should:
`echo $totalPoints[0];`
If you need to debug this kind of issues I recommend you to read about print_r function.